# Create scaffold by skipping the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I have rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8.7

I want to create only a controller and view files for it. Is there any command in rails2.3 that will help me in doing this. I know this can be done in rails 3, but is there a way to do this in rails 2.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just say `script/generate controller [controller_name] [action_name_1] [action_name_2] ...` in the Rails directory to create a controller with the given actions and corresponding view files.

Comment: will you please read the question once again, I want to create **only the controller and view files** and skip the model and migration files

Comment: `script/generate controller` will only create the controller, not the views (nor model, nor migration). It is the closest there is to what you want in rails 2.3. For completeness: `script/generate scaffold` generates the whole shebang :)

Comment: No, it'll generate the view files too, as long as you supply their names after the controller name on the command line.